# For loop in R does not work correctly

Tags: r, for-loop

This is in continuation for my previous question on keyword extraction from a string in R: [Extract a specific key word from a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268906/extract-a-specific-key-word-from-a-string-in-r)

I have written the following code that returns the keyword as i wish:

```
loc <- t1$place
loc <- gsub('"', '', loc)
loc <- gsub(',', '', loc)
for(i in 1:nrow(t1)) 
  country <- word(loc[i], 19, sep=fixed(" : "))
country <- gsub(' }', '', country)
```

The for loop does not seem to work correctly. When I use the same code insde for loop with hardcoded numbers as shown below:

```
country <- word(loc[2], 19, sep=fixed(" : "))
country <- gsub(' }', '', country)
```

The code seems to work. But when I put it through a loop, it gives me an error

```
Error in word[loc, "start"] : subscript out of bounds
```

Please help me where it is going wrong.

```
class(country)
```

says it is a character type. Is the way I coded the for loop wrong??

Other details: t1 is the dataframe of my table. I used Import dataset to load my file week_tweet_filtered.csv and used the command:

```
t1 <- week_tweet_filtered
```

to load the same in t1 variable. I access the place column of my table using t1$place. Also, the place column contains fields of the format:

```
{ "id" : "94965b2c45386f87", "name" : "New York", "boundingBoxCoordinates" : [ [ { "longitude" : -79.76259, "latitude" : 40.477383 }, { "longitude" : -79.76259, "latitude" : 45.015851 }, { "longitude" : -71.777492, "latitude" : 45.015851 }, { "longitude" : -71.777492, "latitude" : 40.477383 } ] ], "countryCode" : "US", "fullName" : "New York, USA", "boundingBoxType" : "Polygon", "URL" : "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/94965b2c45386f87.json", "accessLevel" : 0, "placeType" : "admin", "country" : "United States" }
```

Comment: Why are you not just dealing with the json?  See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061897/parse-json-with-r

Comment: I have tried doing that. But it throws an error saying there should be single quotes delimiting the string which my table does not have. 

`loc <- fromJSON(t1$place)
Error in fromJSON(t1$place) : 
  STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'integer'`

I have tried `loc <- fromJSON(as.character(t1$place))` as someone suggested previously but that reads only the first row. using for loop gives the same error. I believe there is something wroong with the for loop alone.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
x<-'{ "id" : "94965b2c45386f87", "name" : "New York", "boundingBoxCoordinates" : [ [ { "longitude" : -79.76259, "latitude" : 40.477383 }, { "longitude" : -79.76259, "latitude" : 45.015851 }, { "longitude" : -71.777492, "latitude" : 45.015851 }, { "longitude" : -71.777492, "latitude" : 40.477383 } ] ], "countryCode" : "US", "fullName" : "New York, USA", "boundingBoxType" : "Polygon", "URL" : "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/94965b2c45386f87.json", "accessLevel" : 0, "placeType" : "admin", "country" : "United States" }'
y<-fromJSON(x)
y[['country']]
```

Notice that the first line encloses the json in single quotes ... I don't know if that is the problem you are having.

If you don't have the quotes try

```
x<-as.string(t1$place)
```

I don't really understand how you are getting that not as a string.

Comment: This works for me too. like when I write each one manually by adding the single quotes myself. But I can't do this for the entire table which has about 2 million records. So I wanted to use the for loop.

Comment: why don't you just concatenate the single quotes?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but can you please tell me how to do that. I am using r for the first time and am not aware of lot of things.